# Bootstrap display fields info

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display info about selected fields like in this picture
[image]

I tried popover but it displays a dialog. It's possible to have this result using some borderless popover or something else?

```
   <select class="form-control" data-content="This is content." data-   toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Title"></select>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ html: true });
 </script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Something like tooltip http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips ?

Comment: I want the info to be in the right side of the form and wrapped if it passes the border.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/55/

**HTML**

```
<form action="" class="form">
    <select class="form-control" name="" id="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="This is tooltip">
        <option value="">This is option</option>
        <option value="">This is option</option>
        <option value="">This is option</option>
    </select>
        <select class="form-control" name="" id="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Lorem ipsum Dolor">
        <option value="">This is option</option>
        <option value="">This is option</option>
        <option value="">This is option</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

**CSS**

```
.form {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I want the tooltip or popover to be transparent and "docked" in the right side of panel.

Comment: What do you mean 'docked'?